# jQuery window resize trouble

Tags: jquery, resize, window

The following code should only trigger once (on load and window resize) on screen sizes above 768px:

```
$('.content').css('margin', parseInt($('.banner').css('height')) + parseInt($('.content').css('margin')));
```

I don't want it to trigger at all on sizes below 768px. This is not working since it triggers more than once on resize and doesn't remove it below 768px:

```
$(function() {
    $(window).resize(function() {
        if($(this).width() >= 768) {
            $('.content').css('margin', parseInt($('.banner').css('height')) + parseInt($('.content').css('margin')));
        }
    }); 
});
```

Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zgxir

Anybody with a solution?

Comment: im not sure that you can use $(this) for $(window), did you try if($(window).width() >=768) ?

Comment: Do you realize that `.resize()` is called many, many times during an end-user resize operation?  You get many of the intermediate points while the window is being resized - it is not just triggered once at the final size.

Comment: @jfriend00 Yes I know. I don't know I whether I should use `.resize()` or not. But I don't want it to trigger if you resize your window below 768px.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if just need to trigger the code once why not just:

```
$(function() {    
  if ( $(window).width() >= 768 ) {
    //yourcode here
    $('.content').css('margin', parseInt($('.banner').css('height')) + parseInt($('.content').css('margin')));
  }
});
```

Edit- If you want to dynamically change on windows resize you could do:

```
$(function() {
  var 
  bh = $('.banner').css('height'),        
  bm = $('.content').css('margin');
  $(window).resize(function() {
    if($(window).width() >= 768) 
    {
      $('.content').css('margin', bh+bm);
    }
    else 
    {
      $('.content').attr('style','');
    }
  });
});
```

It's important to put the variables outside the windows resize event or else they will be forever incrementing when the window changes size. I use an else statement that cleans the style attribute of the div in order to return the styles to the original state.

Comment: I have tried this but it only works onload, I don't want it to trigger if you resize you window below 768px. Maybe I have to do an if/else statement?

Comment: I updated the answer, I hope this is what you were looking for

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. `else {$('.content').attr('style','');}` does the trick. Nice work, thanks!

Comment: Although it does not seem to work in firefox, no problem on webkit, demo http://codepen.io/michaelnie/pen/AtCoL

Comment: there seem to be a problem with the paseInt() function in firefox. Just remove it an it will run fine.

Comment: It will run if you change `bm = parseInt($('.content').css('margin'));` to `bm = parseInt($('.content').css('margin-top'));`

Answer (score 0):

What you may be looking for is this

```
$(function() {
    var flag = false;
    $(window).resize(function() {
        console.log($(window).width())
        var width = $(window).width();
        if (!flag && width >= 768) {
            flag = true;
            console.log('set')
            $('.content').css('margin', parseInt($('.banner').css('height')) + parseInt($('.content').css('margin')));
        } else if (width < 768) {
            flag = false;
        }
    });

});
```

Demo: [Here](http://codepen.io/arunpjohny/pen/tyKoc)

Comment: It still trigger when you resize your window below 768px.

Comment: @michael You don't want the event fire for screen with width < 768 or you don't want the event to execute `$('.content').css('margin', parseInt($('.banner').css('height')) + parseInt($('.content').css('margin')));` if the current window width < 768

Comment: I don't want the event to execute `$('.content').css('margin', parseInt($('.banner').css('height')) + parseInt($('.content').css('margin')));` if the current window width < 768.

Comment: If you see this demo http://codepen.io/arunpjohny/pen/tyKoc the alert happens only when you size move from < 768 to >= 768 size. Once it is >= 768 any resize at this range will not trigger the alert

Comment: Yes is works as it should if you resize your window from < 768 to > 768 but not the other way around. See this CSS demo http://codepen.io/michaelnie/pen/Estdy

Answer (score 0):

the problem is not with javascript it's with css properties of the (.content) div. because neither it or it's parent has a width value it will expand on resize regardless of the screen's width. resize is not triggering when screen width is < 768.

however you can set minimum width with css:

```
.content{
    min-width: 768px;
}
```